# Libvirt api Lubuntu 16.04/18.04 shutdown confirmation prompt

Tags: lubuntu, virtualization

I'm using Libvirt api to start and stop a VM. VM has Lubuntu 16.04 installed. But when I try to shutdown VM by "virDomainShutdown(dom)" (in C program), it doesn't shutdown and stops at the confirmation prompt in Lubuntu. The confirmation prompt asks for options like shutdown, reboot, logout ,etc..

I want the system to directly shutdown without asking for confirmation.

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'm only using this for educational purposes. So no risk

Comment: Shutdown only sends an info to the guest, it does whatever it is configured to do so (the same as single power button press by default). Options are here (https://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt-domain.html#virDomainShutdownFlagValues). Instead you can kill it (like when power is cut) via https://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt-domain.html#virDomainDestroy but at your own data-risk.

Comment: Thanks, but I had no option other than installing Lubuntu 20.04. And it works perfectly fine in it as 20.04 version doesn't have confirmation popup.